# I'm having an issue with my form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-for

I'm currently running into a problem with my form.

```
First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty
```

in my comments/new which is a partial as _new.html.erb. This is the file:

```
<% form_for @comment do |f| %>
 <%= f.label :body %>
 <%= f.text_field :body, placeholder: "Write Message here.." %>
<% end %>
```

What I'm trying to do is render add a comment to an Article#Show page.

My code:

*Comments Controller*

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

 before_action :find_comment, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

 def index
  @comments = Comment.all
 end

 def new
  @comment = Comment.new
 end

 def create
  @comment = current_user.comments.build(comment_params)
  if @comment.save
   redirect_to :back
  else
   redirect_to '/'
  end
 end

 def show
 end

 def edit
 end

 def update
  if @comment.update(comment_params)
   redirect_to '/'
  else
   redirect_to :back
  end
 end

 def destroy
  @comment.destroy
  redirect_to "/"
 end

 private

 def find_comment
  @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
 end

 def comment_params
  params.require(:comment).permit(:body)
 end
end
```

*Articles#Show*

```
<%= render '/comments/new' %>
```

If there is additional code required on my part. Please ask and I'll edit/update the question with additional files.

All help/explanation is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I understand. I'll remove the second part. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: Are you following any tutorials?

Comment: @Hizqeel Not currently. Haven't touched Rails in a while and was hoping to do a basic blog from what I remembered and searching StackOverFlow for past post regarding any issue I may run into. Possibly best I watch a tutorial all over again.

Comment: What is your current problem? As you have commented under Ruslan answer your problem is solved. Please Update your question accordingly what are you trying to do and what you want to achieve, also add  `params` to `comments_controller.rb`.

Comment: @Hizqeel Thank you. I forgot to update params into this question. I'm having a different problem where I can't send a comment since it's being rollback. I send Ruslan what my console is outputting since it seems like it's not saving.

Comment: If you do `save!` you will get the error message that is preventing the comment from being saved.

Comment: @Iceman Wow I never knew that. Something new I just learned for the future. Thank you. So the error is ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid (Validation failed: Post must exist). Is it because the comment isn't being correctly associated with the Article#show page?

Comment: Yes, the comment is not being linked to an existing `Article` object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First question:

*Add into Article#Show*

```
 def show
  @comment = Comment.new
 end
```

Comment: Thank you. That has the form showing now on the articles show page. I have an additional question I hope you can help me with. When I try submitting the form I get a rollback in my console. Might know why that is the case? I add comment_params to my controller as I noticed it was missing.

Comment: @StevenOssorio  what does the log say?

Comment: @Rusian Started POST "/comments" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-02-15 16:42:28 -0500
Processing by CommentsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"+S9KFMtuwRAUBTJCpXqhShDGrMU9Jyyu9y5kA0StpdB+n4iBvwWgXAXIxp/fMbNxmgEg4tGW3cH6RkHBSIs+/A==", "comment"=>{"body"=>"yo"}, "commit"=>"Create Comment"}
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 11], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
   (0.0ms)  rollback transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Completed 302 Found in 3ms (ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)

Comment: @StevenOssorio no idea. Looks like its not saving properly

Comment: Thank you. I gave you the check since you did help me with my initial question in showing the form. Thank you again :)